# Why does "Nighttime Birds" associate night with warmth?

Tags: song-lyrics, the-gathering

The lyrics to *Nighttime Birds*, the title track from the album of the same name by *The Gathering*, are as follows:

> Their ways are open
>   they spread as their wings
>   they want to be certain
>   of a warm surrounding
>
> When they fly
>   through the night as beautiful
>   nighttime birds
>
> The warm wind picks them up
>
> When they fly
>   through the night as beautiful
>   nighttime birds

I'm particularly interested in the lines "they want to be certain / of a warm surrounding" and "The warm wind picks them up". Why is this associated with **nighttime** birds? Typically, you wouldn't associate "night" with "warm winds" and wanting to be sure of a warm surrounding, but the lyrics are quite specific that they want to be certain of a warm surrounding "when they fly through the night."

Or, are they merely seeking warmth *in the midst of* the night?

A third (rather literal) interpretation is that the song's referring to the fact that migrating birds tend to try to catch warmer "updrafts" by opening their wings to "catch" it. There are a few birds that are either nocturnal or frequently migrate at night, so I suppose that it's *plausible* at least that the author was thinking of that.

Is there an authoritative source on which one the author was referring to? Or are there other possibilities that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: A "bird" can be a colloquialism for a woman.  A night-time bird, then, might be a "woman" "of the night".  This would mean the warmth, instead of being thermal, might be ... hormonal.